# How to override php class in magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, overrides

I want to make changes in the PHP file of a third-party module installed in Magento 1.9.x

The path of the file is app/code/community/Fooman/PdfCustomiser/Model/Mypdf.php

I want to change this class **class Fooman_PdfCustomiser_Model_Mypdf extends TCPDF**

how can I override this in my local module?

What are the steps I need to follow?

Answer (score -1):

Copy the file to

app/code/local/Fooman/PdfCustomiser/Model/Mypdf.php

And then make the edits

Edit

To override Magento core files, it is not necessary to create your own module and write XML in config.xml. Instead, just copy the core file, which you want to edit/override and paste in ‘app/code/local/Mage’. Let’s start by editing the file, Magento will read your file instead of the core file. Suppose as an example if you need to override ‘app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product.php’ you need it to put in Product.php ‘app/code/local/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product.php’. Now, Magento will read your file inside local folder and this process is known as overriding Magento core functionality.

There are some factors to be considered which opting this approach :

For one thing, we must override the complete core file and copy all the class functions. Once the overridden file is in place, this will be the file will be used instead of Magento core file always.
This approach can be used only when you’re testing/developing your module.

Instead of writing a whole module, you can quickly override the core class see if things work well.

Comment: Is it this much only?

Comment: Yes that is correct. The only thing you need to do more for are controllers. There are lots of posts on stack overflow already but here is an example of controller https://stackoverflow.com/q/32866467/10121426 but to be clear local overrides work for blocks, helpers, models

Comment: If I could, i would downvote again. Copy to local scope should be latest approach.

Comment: @sv3n The best approach would be to switch to Magento 2

Comment: Essentially what I'm saying is what's the reason not for local overrides? Because this might cause issues with extension upgrades. Core upgrades on 1.9 aren't going to happen. Upgrades on the above extension are extremely unlikely. Therefore the most time effective method is the local override. I'm fully supportive of best pratice but not on a framework that's about to sunset.

Comment: @DominicXigen That's true, but the last sentence is wrong.There are companies that will stay on M1 and switched to OpenMage LTS ... (for a very good reason IMHO)

Comment: I've been following openmage LTS. On paper a great idea  Unfortunately I've also seen recent email comms from paypal, adyen and Visa all suggesting restrictions and even account closure unless merchants upgrade https://github.com/OpenMage/magento-lts/issues/975